# Equality constraints not met in Whale Optimization Algorithm despite the penalty

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using Matlab and the Whale Optimization [Algorithm](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55667-the-whale-optimization-algorithm) to optimize my system of dimension 11. There are some equality constraints that I need to keep (i.e x(2)-x(1)-90, x(4)-x(3)=60...). I know that with these types of optimization algorithms penalty functions must be used in order to solve constrained questions (according to the paper in the same link).

My objective function is called House_cost and I added a penalty condition inside the cost function.

```
if((x(2)-x(1))~= 90)
C=inf;
end
```

Where C is my cost, I also tried setting it to a really big value.The rest of the bounds and parameters are set as the following:

```
    dim = 11;
    Max_iteration =1000;
    SearchAgents_no = 30;
    lb = [1    1      1       1    2 1 50 3 19 1 1];
    ub = [1440  1440   1440   1440   5 3 80 10 24 3 200];
    fobj=@House_cost;
    Function_name='House_cost';

    tic;
    [Best_score,xbest,WOA_cg_curve]=WOA(SearchAgents_no,Max_iteration,lb,ub,dim,fobj);
    toc;
```

When I run my program, the constraints are not met, in fact x(2)-x(1)=-73 in my final attempt. What could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

These type of random search algorithms are not very good in handling equality constraints. Sometimes you can substitute out a variable instead:

x2-x1=90

means

x2 = 90+x1

so you can remove the variable `x2` and the constraint `x2-x1=90` from the model.

Otherwise use other technologies that can handle simultaneous equations better, such as integer programming (piecewise linear), nonlinear programming, etc.

Comment: I tried this aswell and it didn't work, my output was stuck at inf with no optimum value achieved. The paper of the algorithm mentioned using this algorithm to solve multiple constrained problems and they used penalty as well, so I don't know what went wrong. Also, do you have suggestions on good algorithms for constrained optimization.

Comment: Looks like things are seriously messed up. Logically speaking, it is very difficult for a variable that is removed from the model to cause problems. Often it helps to first formulate a proper mathematical model before trying to solve it (this is like designing a car before building it). Depending on the model one can select a suitable algorithm or technology to solve it. I often see users selecting the algorithm first, which almost never makes sense.

Comment: Well, I didn't get your point when it comes to removing a variable. I have tried two Algorithms with this same system before and the constraints were met. I tried GA and Direct search from Matlab's Global Optimization toolbox, now I want to explore other options, reason why I posted my question.

Comment: "I didn't get your point" and "I tried this aswell and it didn't work" are really contradictory statements: they cannot be both true.